# How to display the calendar using modal datetime picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal, react-native-datetimepicker

I am using the [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) library and I am trying to use the display prop to display the calendar. If you look at my reproducible example found on [snack expo here](https://snack.expo.dev/id-KD9UDH), you can see the issue I am having. I have also posted the code below.

The issue I am having is that when you hit 'Show Data Picker', you can see it renders this bottom modal with the current date. If you press the date, the calendar renders. **How can I skip the first bottom modal that gets rendered? I just want to go straight to the calendar.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

const Example = () => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    console.warn("A date has been picked: ", date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
      <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
        display={"default"}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

The calendar I want, but without the bottom modal that renders, I want just the calendar.
[image]

Comment: I have gone through your problem statement and I can see that is not the issue as you can see the exact implementation for the same on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are saying please? I do not understand. Yes, I pulled my example from their readMe, and in both examples, the modal pops up. I do not want the first modal.

Comment: see since you have used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker that's why you are getting the modal with the current date like this only so you can use this library to fix your issue https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-datepicker.

Comment: I guess you need to change in library it self and use it as patch-package as [shown here](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/557)

Answer (score 0):

set `display` prop to `inline` instead of `calendar`

```js
display={"inline"}
```

for more details see the documentation about this: [here](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker#can-i-use-the-new-ios-14-style-for-the-datetime-picker)

Comment: The first modal still pops up. Have you tried this in the expo?

Comment: Yes, i tried it in the expo link you provided

Comment: So that is a different calendar than the one I need. If you set the display to "default", you can see the calendar I need. I will update the question

Comment: If you want the pre iOS 14 wheel based date picker, you should set `display={'spinner'}` instead of `inline`.

Comment: I need the calendar I refer to in the original post

Comment: @guts716 Display `inline` or `spinner` ARE the calenders you refer to in the original post. What other calender are you looking for. Do you have an image? I have tested them both on my device and they match with your Expo Snack.

Comment: inline and spinner both produce calendars that do not load the first modal, which is what I want. BUT the calendar that inline and spinner produces is visually a different calendar. I have updated my question to include a image of the calendar I want. In the image, you can see a bottom modal is rendered before the calendar. I do not want that first bottom modal to render.

Comment: @guts716 What you see is the modal from the library you are using. It’s built in. If you don’t want it just don’t use the package and instead use a different lib like https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/date-time-picker/